# Translating rdist configuration with multiple roots to rsync

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I am implementing rdist similar syntax to rsync and I am able sync my files and folders with rsync, but while handling this rdist syntax I am not understanding this part `except (/home/user1/log1/*/*/sql.net` `/home/user1/log1/*/*/core)` and my include files of rdist are `FILES=(/home/user1/log1 /home/user1/rightlog)`

How do I achieve this in rsync? I have tried this `rsync -rtu --exclude='/log1/*/*/sql.net' exclude='/log1/*/*/core' $FILES remote@host:$FILES`

Am I cloning exact rdist or do I need to tweak more? I am not getting the desired output, and moreover, sometimes `sql.net` may be present in the other folders, so I cannot do this `--exclude=sql.net`.

Answer (score 1):

Even without exclude lists, `rsync $FILES remote@host:$FILES` wouldn't work: it expands to `rsync /home/user1/log1 /home/user1/rightlog remote@host:/home/user1/log1 /home/user1/rightlog` which would make `/home/user1/rightlog` the destination (but rsync will complain that you're mixing local and remote sources).

You can specify multiple sources with rsync, but they're all copied to the same destination and parameters such as exclude lists apply to all the sources.

If you need different parameters for different subtrees, then you need to make separate calls to rsync. If you don't need different parameters, then synchronize the common root but include only the parts that you want to synchronize.

```
rsync --include='/log1' --include='/rightlog' --exclude='/*' /home/user1 remote@host:/home/user1
```

You don't need separate calls to rsync to have different exclude lists as they just need to include the leading path component.

```
rsync --include='/log1' --include='/rightlog' --exclude='/*' \
      --exclude='/log1/*/*/sql.net' --exclude='/log1/*/*/core' \
      /home/user1 remote@host:/home/user1
```

Comment: great .. but i need to embedd all includes in array variable FILES and everything will go in test.sh which will called by cron.I don't want separate file  for include also or all include at command line rsync, should use variable and i will traverse trough for loop i am using SUN os sparc enterprise.

Comment: @chandu So construct the rsync command line by iterating over the array.